# Can I copy multiple files from single folder to multiple folder in windows with batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, file-transfer

I have a folder(D:office) with 10 pdf files (files name are random). I want to copy each of them serially in new 10 folders(D\alpha\a.... D\alpha\j). is it possible?

Edit: I am sorry for poor English, I am not a native user. What I meant to ask was the automated solution not a manual copy and paste.

Comment: Obviously that's possible, for example you could drag&drop these files in each target directory. You should be more specific about what kind of solution you're looking for.

Comment: open both folders.  Copy and paste the files into both windows.  This has been possible for nearly 30 years

Comment: Actually I just gave example using 10 files, I have hundreds of files to do same. So, copy&paste will be the manual solution but I am seeking for some specific quick solution.

Answer (score 2):

There is no quick solution. Copy and Paste at this time is all you can do. Highlight all the PDF's in the folder, then open up a new folder and do **Ctrl+V** to paste. Repeat in each folder.

You can possibly select all of the files you want to copy by highlighting them, using **Ctrl+C**, then selecting all the folders you want to copy them to, by using **Ctrl+Click**, then right click on one of the folders and choose paste. This should solve your issue. As mentioned in the comments. Unless you want to create a program that will do this, these steps are your best option.

Comment: This is a correct answer, so you don't really deserve the downvote. Superuser is not a script-writing service. Of course it's possible to do it in a batch or powershell script, but that's not what OP is asking.

Comment: @Joe VanHorn +1 tags are windows and file-transfer.

Comment: So scripts aren't SuperUser but individual commands are? Or no? The script is simply for easy execution. Also, that is what the OP was asking for. If I misinterpreted and it's not what's being asked, are we suppose to not mention a relatively easy and significantly quicker solution because it's asked in the correct forum but the answer isn't?

Comment: @RJFalconer that was my first question, I had batch file as a "Tag" but it was edited and removed by moderator or someone (?).

Comment: @BiTinerary thank you, you got my question and I have to mention I am new here and also I am not a native English speaker (sorry for my bad English)

Comment: @Oliver Salzburg Why did you remove the tag?

Comment: @BiTinerary Your answer is good, the question was bad. I believe the questions SU is trying to avoid are ones that show no effort: "I know nothing about cmdline. Here's what I'm trying to do. Help" with no evidence that they've tried something themselves. Really, the best response here imo would have been for us to fix the question.

Comment: Oh, ok. That make sense I think I also responded after some edits were made. Thanks for clearing that up for me though, will keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [Robocopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx), [Xcopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771254.aspx) or [copy](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/240268) commands for windows. Edit the following code to fit your needs, write into a notepad and save with `.bat` extension.

`Robocopy D:\Office\*.pdf D:\YourNewFolder1
Robocopy D:\Office\*.pdf D:\YourNewFolder2
Robocopy D:\Office\*.pdf D:\YourNewFolder3`

The `*` character is called a wildcard. It copies ALL file names with the `.pdf` extension into the following directory location. If the new folder name doesn't exist, it will be created. I also believe the default function of robocopy is to copy alphabetically/numerically so that should solve your need to copy via serial. If not, you can use `D:\office\*1.pdf` in the example and that will copy all files, with any name, ending with a 1. Rinse and repeat for the extent of your series.

Also check out the flags that are available for any/each command as they may also be helpful. ie: Recursively copy within a directory, don't copy specific files/folders, etc...